# in joining redundancy sum getting

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My Query is (in this query we get the redundancy result wrong value getting )

```
SELECT 
ggk_user.user_id,
ggk_user.user_email,
SUM(ggk_shop_item.item_price) as total_amount,
SUM(ggk_userpayment.up_amount) as paid
FROM ggk_user

LEFT JOIN ggk_product ON ggk_user.user_id = ggk_product.product_user_id
LEFT JOIN ggk_shop_item ON ggk_product.product_id = ggk_shop_item.item_product_id
INNER JOIN ggk_userpayment ON ggk_user.user_id = ggk_userpayment.up_user_id 


WHERE ggk_user.user_type = 1
AND ggk_user.user_status = 1


GROUP BY ggk_user.user_id,ggk_userpayment.up_user_id
```

IF run this query.

```
SELECT 
ggk_user.user_id,
ggk_user.user_email,
SUM(ggk_shop_item.item_price) as total_amount
FROM ggk_user

LEFT JOIN ggk_product ON ggk_user.user_id = ggk_product.product_user_id
LEFT JOIN ggk_shop_item ON ggk_product.product_id = ggk_shop_item.item_product_id


WHERE ggk_user.user_type = 1
AND ggk_user.user_status = 1


GROUP BY ggk_user.user_id,ggk_userpayment.up_user_id
```

this query working fine so issue in 3rd join due to 3rd join user id equal to user table user id so how to fix this error?

Comment: Please show your expected output vs actual output from the first query. Also any relevant parts of your database structure.

Comment: The cardinality between the tables is inflating your counts.  you have to use inline views to generate the totals before you join.  That way the cardinality doesn't artificially inflate the sums'

Comment: actual result this . 
user_id | user_email  | total_amount | paid
1   |abc@gmail.com | 41.25   | 17.00
But getting this result.
user_id | user_email  | total_amount | paid
1   |abc@gmail.com | 247.5   | 69.00
@ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inline view to generate the paid amount from GGK_USERpayment so the cardinality between the tables doesn't effect the other sums.

Something like the below; but we may need to also generate an inline view for the total_amount.  I don't understand the relationships between the tables well enough to know if it's needed.

```
SELECT ggk_user.user_id
     , ggk_user.user_email
     , SUM(ggk_shop_item.item_price) as total_amount
     , ggk_userpayment.paid
FROM ggk_user
INNER JOIN (SELECT sum(up_Amount) as Paid, up_user_ID 
            FROM ggk_userpayment
            GROUP BY up_user_ID ) ggk_userpayment 
   ON ggk_user.user_id = ggk_userpayment.up_user_id
LEFT JOIN ggk_product 
   ON ggk_user.user_id = ggk_product.product_user_id
LEFT JOIN ggk_shop_item 
   ON ggk_product.product_id = ggk_shop_item.item_product_id
WHERE ggk_user.user_type = 1
  AND ggk_user.user_status = 1
GROUP BY ggk_user.user_id
       , ggk_userpayment.up_user_id
```